# SUM function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are three tables,we have to select data from these table using one primary key and foreign key. But in the one table there is lot of data in the third table. We have to sum the data on the base of the primary key.

[image: Table1]  [image: Table2] [image: table3]

```
BAl = Balance, met = Method, amo = amount, cst_id, cut_id, cut_i = customer_id
```

Now we have to sum the on the basis of method and sum for 10 cust id in the same query. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: @MahmoudGamal thats reason i have display the scema of table

Comment: i have to select 10 customer same time

Answer (score 0):

If you give some sample data it will be easier to write queries to help you.
But if your `MET` field is numerical and you want to sum it then you need.

```
select
   t1.cst_n, t2.bal,
   sum(t3.met) as met,
   sum(t3.amo) as amo
from table1 as t1
   inner join table2 as t2 on t2.cut_id = t1.cst_id
   inner join table3 as t3 on t3.cut_i = t1.cst_id
group by t1.cst_n, t2.bal
```

well if you want to sum data for all 10 customers into one number, may be you just need

```
select
   sum(t3.met) as met,
   sum(t3.amo) as amo
from table3 as t3
where t3.cut_i in (select t.customerid from @<your variable table with cust. ids> as t)
```

Comment: it will give for one customer only .... i require the same for 10 customer in one query

Comment: please give test data. this query grouping customers by `cst_n` (supposed customer number)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte 
AS
(
    SELECT 
      *, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  t1.cst_id) RowNum
    FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 
            ON t1.cst_id = t2.cut_id
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3 
            ON t2.cut_id = t3.customer_id 
           AND t2.BAL = t3.Balance 
           AND t2.amo = t3.amount
)
SELECT SUM(*)
FROM cte
WHERE RowNum Between 1 AND 10
-- You can add a GROUP BY here
```

Comment: @Ashishsingh - It is [Common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), I used it, just for readability, and for pagination to let you select sum for 10 customers each time. You can write it using a sub query.